# Insert or replace doesn't work

Tags: sqlite, sql-insert

I need to do an insert or replace into an existing db, but it don't work correctly.

example:

```
select * from tab where name = 'foo';
6530|foo|ok|||
insert or replace into tab values('foo', 'ok', 1, 2, 3);
select * from tab where name = 'foo';
6530|foo|ok|||
43523|foo|ok|1|2|3
```

why the insert-replace doesn't "update" the existing fields into the record 6530 and it creates a new one?

the table:

```
create table tab(
    id integer unique primary key,
    name text not null,
    tipo text not null,
    val1 integer,
    val2 integer,
    val3 integer
);
```

Comment: what is your problem insert or update menas your query is  too wrong,... so, first of all you should clear post your problem...

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a unique index on one or a combination of the columns like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_tab ON tab (name, tipo);
```

The records gets deleted and inserted with the new values when a the same values exists in the table. You can do an UPSERT with the following:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tab (id, name, tipo, val1, val2, val3)
 SELECT old.id, new.name, new.tipo, new.val1, new.val2, val3
 FROM ( SELECT
     'foo' AS name,
     'ok' AS tipo,
     1  AS val1,
     2  AS val2,
     3  AS val3
 ) AS new
 LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT id, name, tipo, val1, val2, val3
     FROM tab
 ) AS old ON new.name= old.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert Or Update command works leveraged on the unique key defined. The reason 2 different rows are after the Ins or Upd is because of you are not passing the unique ID the engine needs to perform the update, and instead (because of a lacking of ID) is doing Insert.
After your query:

```
select * from tab where name = 'foo';
```

Execute:

```
insert or replace into tab values(ID, foo', 'ok', 1, 2, 3);
```

while the ID is the one got from the previous query (i.e. 6530)

Now the row will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

***Example for: Insert or replace doesn't work***

*Assuming 3 columns in the table.. ID, NAME, ROLE*

*BAD: This will insert or replace all columns with new values for ID=1:*

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Employee (id, name, role) 
  VALUES (1, 'John Foo', 'CEO');
```

*BAD: This will insert or replace 2 of the columns... the NAME column will be set to NULL or the default value:*

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Employee (id, role) 
  VALUES (1, 'code monkey');
```

*GOOD: This will update 2 of the columns. When ID=1 exists, the NAME will be unaffected. When ID=1 does not exist, the name will be default (NULL).*

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Employee (id, role, name) 
  VALUES (  1, 
            'code monkey',
            (SELECT name FROM Employee WHERE id = 1)
          );
```

*This will update 2 of the columns. When ID=1 exists, the ROLE will be unaffected. When ID=1 does not exist, the role will be set to 'Benchwarmer' instead of the default value.*

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Employee (id, name, role) 
  VALUES (  1, 
            'Susan Bar',
            COALESCE((SELECT role FROM Employee WHERE id = 1), 'Benchwarmer')
          );
```